# Android - HttpClient error

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm trying to get a web page content

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

"client.execute(request)" is marked as an error, "Unhandled exception type ClientProtocolException"
how to fix that?

EDIT

using Try Catch

```
try{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);    
}catch(Exception e){
    //Handle Error here
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dlgAlert.setMessage("OK OK");
    dlgAlert.setTitle("OK");
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

and running the app, the alert is shown,

internet connection present.

Network usage permission added to androidmanifest.xml

EDIT
I want to get a web page content,, I followed tutorials, and previuos questions,, all codes I tried fail at this point.
full code:

```
package com.example.internetsql;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



public void connect(View view) 
{

    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);    
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle Error here
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        dlgAlert.setMessage("OK OK");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("OK");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }





}



}
```

Comment: In general these 3 lines of code should work... Can you paste the complete exception that you get? ... You may need a try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

You need to either surround the code with a try/catch block or add a throws declaration to whatever method this is getting called from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either throw the ClientProtocolException from the method you are executing this inside of. Or surround this with a try, catch block to handle the expection within the method itself.

```
try
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
}
catch (ClientProtocolException cpe)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is better than just catching a general exception since you will catch the exception you could reasonably expect to get but you won't accidentally miss an exception you weren't expecting. (Which may indicate a bug in the code or something has gone wrong you hadn't expected).

EDIT:
Android isn't set up in such a way that it will allow you to perform potentially long running tasks in the UI thread. Something like accessing a webpage should normally take place in another thread. You will want to look into how to use an AsyncTask for this.

In the meantime putting this code at the start of your onCreate method should temporarily fix the problem.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I would highly recommend looking into how you use an AsyncTask for internet access before you start trying to do too much in the UI thread. This might work reasonably well in the emulator or even a device connected to Wifi but as soon as you go on a slightly slower mobile connection your UI will become unresponsive while the request is running.

Comment: I added try catch, and the catch lines executed as I explained the the question Edit